# pdfbox : PDTrueTypeFont.loadDescriptorDictionary java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: pdfbox

pdfBox / JSF

Im getting nullpointer exception when trying to load barcode ttf font.

```
InputStream inputStream1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/code128.ttf");
            font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(pdDocto, inputStream1);
```

***If I try with another ttf font It loads with success.***

Stack error :

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.loadDescriptorDictionary

Comment: Can you provide the font for testing?

Comment: Ive downloaded another code128.ttf and it worked fine. I figured it out 5 minutes ago. Tell me how can I upload the .ttf if you want it. thx @mkl

Comment: Well, if you can use the newly found font, everything is ok. If you are forced, though, to use the original one, you can provide it for people here to analyze by sharing it from e.g. your google drive or drop box and adding the URL here.

Comment: The best would be to create an issue with PDFBox JIRA, upload the ttf file there so that the developers can see whether it is a PDFBox bug. This will help the next person. If you're too lazy, just e-mail me the file. Also make sure you're using the latest version, 1.8.6 is the correct one.

Comment: Don't bother, I found two fonts and I've opened two new issues about this, PDFBOX-2165 and PDFBOX-2166.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive downloaded another .ttf and it was resolved.